# Socket получить body html

Tags: c++, c

Отправляю на сервер запрос и получаю данные

```
struct addrinfo hints, *res;
int sockfd;
char buf[2048];

memset(&hints, 0,sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
getaddrinfo("адрес сайта","80", &hints, &res);
sockfd = socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,res->ai_protocol)
connect(sockfd,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen);

send(sockfd,header,strlen(header),0);
recv(sockfd,buf,sizeof(buf),0));
close(sockfd);
```

но проблема в том что вместе с данными приходят и заголовки сервера.Как получить данные без заголовков сервера?

Comment: `getaddrinfo` надо обязательно проверять, иначе сломается все :)

Comment: Проверяю все просто для простоты опустил

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Заголовки сервера - это нормально. В них может быть много полезной инфы. Но одно известно точно - заголовки отделяются от тела ответа двойным переводом - [CR LF CR LF](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html). В байтах это 0x0D 0x0A 0x0D 0x0A.

То есть, ищите эту последовательность и по ней разбиваете. Заголовки слева, тело - справа.

Comment: Может их как то можно не принимать.В общем сервер отдает json его нужно парсить, а заголовки мешают

Comment: используйте curl.

Comment: curl слышал веса подбавит в код.

Comment: конечно добавит. Но зато уберет другие баги.

Comment: какие?Может на ыщслуе tcnm fyfkju CURLOPT_HEADER

Comment: К примеру, Ваш код будет неполучать все тело ответа, если оно длинее 2048. Также, есть такая штука, как KeapAlive, которая может сыграть злую шутку. Но для тестов сойдет и так.

Но если сервер Ваш, то можно вполне написать "свой http", который будет возвращать то, что Вам нужноо

Comment: под android ndk есть curl?

Comment: https://github.com/jahrome/curl-android или https://github.com/OlehKulykov/libnhr

Comment: у курла же вроде есть оф. релиз на андроид https://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Comment: :) забавно, а если сервер в заголовке ответил 404,500,302 ? Чего делать то? Продолжать парсить Джейсона? :) Заголовки надо читать и анализировать, там кстати есть размер 'данных', именно так её большинство и отрезают `(размер принятого - (размер принятого - размер данных))`. А если ещё это и http 1.1, то передача ещё может быть и чанками (фрагментами)

Comment: Да http 1.Если выкинит ошибку то понятно - это вместо чтения заголовков.Читать это парсить?Не дело.Да и к тому же размер данных туда не приходит.

Comment: Да и по методике удаленичя 0x0D 0x0A 0x0D 0x0A срезает еще и пол json

Comment: не нужно их удалять - нужно разделить по этому разделителю. И только один раз - в теле (там где json) может быть куча таких разделителей.

Comment: А какую ошибку он выкинет? Ошибка только в заголовках может быть. Ошибки сокета не имеют никакой взаимосвязи с http протоколом.